# How to convert dapper stored procedure result in Datatable in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, dapper

Below is my method CallRetrieve() which call stored procedure using Dapper ORM. I want to convert that stored procedure result into Datatable. How it is possible.

```
public DataTable CallRetrieve(string UserLogin)
{
    using (IDbConnection db = CreateConnection())
    {
        DataTable table = db.Query<DataTable>(queryHolder.GET_USER, new { @UserLogin = UserLogin }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).FirstOrDefault();
        return table;
    }
}
```

Comment: DataTable is a collection, have you tried DataRow?

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 3):

As you said, Dapper is used more as an ORM, which is used to map the results to produce an instance of a class (probably using reflection to map public properties to stored proc result column names).

For populating DataSets and DataTables, I would suggest using ADO.Net's DataAdapter which is well documented on msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254931(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z(v=vs.110).aspx

You will be able to call the adapter's "Fill" method to put the stored procedure results into the DataSet (DataSet contains a collection of DataTables). Once populated, you can return the DataTable contained in the DataSet